Error with Docker Compose: FATAL: data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has invalid permissions
When i try to run docker compose up -d i got this error:

FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has invalid
permissions
DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).

Im using Windows and Docker Desktop with Hyper-V without wsl.
Complete logs:
2024-07-13 01:12:30 postgres  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2024-07-13 01:12:30 postgres  | creating subdirectories ... ok
2024-07-13 01:12:30 postgres  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2024-07-13 01:12:30 postgres  | selecting default max_connections ... 20
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | creating configuration files ... ok
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | 2024-07-13 00:12:31.291 UTC [82] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has invalid permissions
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | 2024-07-13 00:12:31.291 UTC [82] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | child process exited with exit code 1
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
2024-07-13 01:12:31 postgres  | running bootstrap script ... 2024-07-13T00:12:34.144214100Z The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2024-07-13 01:12:34 postgres  | This user must also own the server process.
2024-07-13 01:12:34 postgres  | 
2024-07-13 01:12:34 postgres  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2024-07-13 01:12:34 postgres  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2024-07-13 01:12:34 postgres  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

This is what i alredy tried:

chmod 0700 /directory
chmod -R 777 /directory

I also tryed to run docker compose up from admin powershell, but that didn't work either.
The pgadmin image is working fine, the problem is only with the postgres image.
Its my first time using docker on my own.
My docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: auth_db
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres


I can find a couple instances of this error but the only concrete suggestion is to use a Docker named volume instead of a bind mount.  Does making that change help here?
